# If husband start practicing hinduism what his wife shuld do?

Tags: sunni

If husband start practicing Hinduism what his wife should do?  can she practice her own religion Islam and be with her husband who is now practicing Hinduism?

Answer (score 3):

As per my knowledge, the marriage will be broken and the two can not practice husband wife relation, they are now strangers for each other. Below are few rulings passed by Jamia Binoria India, a well reputed Sunni school of thought. For more details and possibilities for living together, you should definitely consult Islamic scholars.

[Muslim marrying a Hindu](http://www.jamiabinoria.net/efatawa/2013-4/16920.html)

[Husband accepting Christianity while wife is Muslim](http://www.jamiabinoria.net/efatawa/2013-2/15891.html)

[Hindu wife accepting Islam while Husband is still Hindu](http://www.jamiabinoria.net/efatawa/2011-4/10389.html)

Deep apologies for not providing translated version for all users. If you don't understand the language then you can get help probably from an Indian, Pakistani, Bengali to get it translated for you.

Answer (score -1):

**Quran 60:10**

They are not lawful (wives) to the disbelievers, nor are the disbelievers lawful (husbands) for them.

https://quran.com/60/10?translations=17